# descriptive & inferential statistic for raster pixel value in R

Tags: r, statistics, classification, raster

for starter please note that i'm new on statistic

here's snip of my training dataset that contain 4 bands of image(RGB & NIR) and it's corresponding land cover class (NIR value is all in 255 as my drone didn't have the necessary sensor, but i plan to upgrade it)

```
B1   B2   B3   B4   class_id
143  144  134  255  1
70   141  90   255  2
197  210  70   255  3
```

I want to test if my semantically labeled class_id is good and distinct enough to make automatic classification give better prediction

My friend said to use descriptive and inferential statistic, anova with lm function (seriously i dont get it at all)

Tried a tutorial which use

```
Summarize(class_id ~ B1 + B2 + B3, data=dfAll)
```

but it's only support 2 factor and others

Any suggestion?

Comment: Couple of questions: Which automatic classification are you planning to use? How many classes do you have? And how much labeled training data do you have?

Comment: i plan to use some pixel based algorithm like RF or SVM. for this one it's 16 class. this training data consists of 1.048.000+ rows

Comment: If you're planning to use RF, you can just train your model and look at the out-of-bag error matrix ... that should give you and idea how well your classes can be separated

Comment: right now i plan to improve the preprocessing, that's to improve the quality of data beforehand. 
your method is good too, but's its after processing

Comment: One thing is to improve data quality, and the other one to see if the classes can be separated as is ... Your qestion states "*I want to test if my semantically labeled class_id is good and distinct enough"*, which is what I meant.

Comment: tre enough, i forgot to tell when i want to process it